# URL Redirection basis of category name

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting

I am working on coldfusion application and using IIS URL rewriting. The URL rewriting rewrite my URL http://www.test.com/viewcategory/1 to http://www.test.com/viewcategory.cfm?category=1. It is working good and open the webpage with category details on the basis of categoryid.

Again i was rewrite my URL http://www.test.com/viewcategory/categoryname to http://www.test.com/viewcategory.cfm?category=categoryname and i want to open category detail page on the basis of categoryname **but dont want to change my code** i.e get details on the basis of categoryid. Is there any way in coldfusion to get internally the id of category on the basis of categoryname and display the page with the above http://www.test.com/viewcategory.cfm?category=categoryname.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: You could query the database for the category ID based on the category name = `select id from category where categoryName = 'moo'`

Comment: To be safe, you might want to do something at the database level to ensure your category names are unique.

Comment: Agreed...you should also have some kind of logic check to make sure that a record is returned when passing in a category name.

Answer (score -1):

```
<cfquery name="getCat" datasource="#request.dsn#">
  select * from Categories
   where CategoryName=<cfqueryparam value="#url.category#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
</cfquery>
```

As one of the comments points out, you need to ensure category names are unique, or you could do like some sites do and include the numbers like viewcategory/Apples/1, viewcategory/Bananas/2 etc then you can rewrite the url to pass the ID, or to work with your current scheme, you could use urls like Bananas_1, Apples_2 and then:

```
<cfset url.cID = val(listlast(url.category,"_"))>
<cfquery name="getCat" datasource="#request.dsn#">
  select * from Categories
   where CategoryID=<cfqueryparam value="#url.cid#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
</cfquery>
```

Edit: Further, you could do this to prevent errant urls having mismatched category names and numeric IDs (Let's say a user missed the last digit when copying a url), though that's not an issue that most websites care about.

```
<cfset url.cID = val(listlast(url.category,"_"))>
<cfset url.category = listDeleteAt(url.category,listlen(url.category,"_"),"_")>
<!--- I chose not to use listfirst above in case your category name includes underscores --->
<cfquery name="getCat" datasource="#request.dsn#">
  select * from Categories
   where CategoryID=<cfqueryparam value="#url.cid#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
     and CategoryName=<cfqueryparam value="#url.category#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
</cfquery>
```

Edit: With minor changes for proper field names, and table names, these queries will work, but as a comment on my answer points out, you should list out the columns you want to retrieve rather than using *. Using * by default is a bad habit get into.

Comment: And what would happen if the user changes the url to `viewcategory/apples/6`? Also....never recommend using `SELECT * FROM...` you should list out the columns you need.

Comment: Users can screw up urls. If they did change it to 6, they'd get 6's category. So? What happens if I change the number in this page's url (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306340/url-redirection-basis-of-category-name/25308378?noredirect=1#comment39449365_25308378)? It changes to a different question.

And yeah, TC should probably list out the column names, I was just giving him queries that would safely work.